# what does **boosted by 15db** mean?

Tags: meaning

This guy is [testing the performance of soundproofing](https://youtu.be/dPzbuEunSLk?t=515).

[image]

[image]

both with and without soundproofing are boosted by 15db

what does boost mean here?

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boost?q=boost%20) gives this explanation about boost

> to improve or increase something

obviously, boost here does not mean increase the sound from inside, which does not make any sense, so what does **boosted by 15db** mean?

I am aware of what **db** means. I am asking what does **boosted** mean here.

Comment: I think he means he has artificially boosted (increased) the sound by 15db on the video (on both 'with' and 'without' recordings), to make it easier for the listener to hear the difference.

Comment: Have you looked up "db" to see what it means?

Comment: I think "all levels" means the boost (or increase per @stevekeiretsu) was made across the entire audible spectrum (i.e, at all sound frequencies).